# Travelling by plane with a stop in China - will I be quarantined?

Tags: japan, china, event-based-effects, western-europe, covid-19

I am going to Japan from Western Europe in March (by plane). I have a stop in Shanghai (~2h. long so I'll stay in airport). Due to the Coronavirus related protective measures, will I be quarantined when arriving to Japan?

**UPDATE - 02-03-2020**

I was able to reschedule my flights for later with no charge, so I chose another company and have direct flights now.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

No, you will not. Japan has banned entry of all foreigners who have travelled to Zhejiang and Hubei provinces within 14 days of travelling to Japan, but Shanghai, a provincial-level city, does not belong to either. You are (so far) safe.

It is, nevertheless, highly possible that Japan will soon extend this travel ban to the entirety of China. Keep updated. As a comment suggests, you are encouraged to keep an eye on the [Timatic news feed](https://www.iatatravelcentre.com/international-travel-document-news.htm), as well as the news.

Note: Take care of where is your next destination (transit or otherwise). For example, if it is Singapore and its within 14 days, Singapore will deny you transit or entry for the 2 hour you spent in China.

Comment: Thank you very much! Is there a website showing these informations and updating them on a daily basis? (I mean either for Japan only or for the whole world)

Comment: @belitd I don't know of such a site, but you can follow the Japan Times, which will likely feature such an expansion of the ban prominently if it happens.

Comment: @belitd The [Timatic news feed](https://www.iatatravelcentre.com/international-travel-document-news.htm) is tracking this; you can find the direct URL for coronavirus restrictions [here](https://www.iatatravelcentre.com/international-travel-document-news/1580226297.htm).

Comment: Yes, you are "so far" safe. Shanghai is not too heavily affected by nCoV-19, but a travel ban on China as a whole seems far from impossible.

Comment: You might be safe for now, but situation is quickly emerging. Most countries, for instance, Singapore, denies even transit for people who went (even transit counts) to mainland China in last 14 days. Keep that in mind for next destination.

Comment: And keep in mind that the 14 days is likely to be expanded to 21 days or even longer soon, as China has already doing that internally and has admitted there have been cases where the incubation time seems to have been more than a month.